# Retrying Method calls in generic way

Tags: java, reflection, frameworks, openframeworks

My Java application requires a retry logic on remote calls failures. 
These remote calls are:

- scattered all over the application
- pertain to different Remote Service classes.

Also, the retry logic may have varying retry interval and varying retry attempts.

I need a generic retry() implementation which can make appropriate method calls depending on from where it is called. Below is a simple code illustration of I am looking for. I know we can attempt to do this using java reflection, but, is there a framework or an open source available somewhere which is read-to-use?

```
try {
 ClassA objA = remoteServiceA.call(paramA1, paramA2, ...);
} catch (Exception e){
 ClassA objA = (ClassA)retry(remoteService, listOfParams, ..); // generic method call
}
..

try {
 ClassB objB = remoteServiceB.call(paramB1, paramB2, ...);
} catch (Exception e){
 ClassA objB = (ClassB)retry(remoteService, listOfParams, ..); // generic method call
}
```

Answer (score 12):

As already suggested, you should use AOP and Java annotations. I would recommend a read-made mechanism from [jcabi-aspects](http://aspects.jcabi.com/annotation-retryonfailure.html) (I'm a developer):

```
@RetryOnFailure(attempts = 3, delay = 5)
public String load(URL url) {
  return url.openConnection().getContent();
}
```

Read also this blog post: http://www.yegor256.com/2014/08/15/retry-java-method-on-exception.html

Update: Check [`RetryFunc`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.cactoos/cactoos/0.10/org/cactoos/func/RetryFunc.html) from [Cactoos](http://www.cactoos.org).

Answer (score 1):

This is a book example of where [aspectj](/questions/tagged/aspectj) (or [aop](/questions/tagged/aop) in general) can be used, see [*8.2.7 Example* in Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-example) and [5 Reasons Java Developers Should Learn and Use AspectJ](http://www.developer.com/print/java/5-reasons-java-developers-should-learn-and-use-aspectj.html).

Basically an aspect intercepts all calls to given methods (specified using annotation, naming convention, whatever) and retries.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have a method, that need to retied at every 500ms and upto 5 times.
**Current class**:

```
public class RemoteCaller{
    Service serviceCaller;
    public void remoteCall(String message) {
                serviceCaller.updateDetails( this.message);
                return null;
    }
}
```

**Modified approach:**

```
public class RetriableHelper<T> implements Callable<T> {

    private Callable<T> task;

    private int numberOfRetries;

    private int numberOfTriesLeft;

    private long timeToWait;


    public RetriableHelper(int numberOfRetries, long timeToWait, Callable<T> task) {
        this.numberOfRetries = numberOfRetries;
        numberOfTriesLeft = numberOfRetries;
        this.timeToWait = timeToWait;
        this.task = task;
    }

    public T call() throws Exception {
        while (true) {
            try {
                return task.call();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw e;
            } catch (CancellationException e) {
                throw e;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                numberOfTriesLeft--;
                if (numberOfTriesLeft == 0) {
                    throw e; 
                }
                Thread.sleep(timeToWait);
            }
        }
    }
}


Backend system/remote call class:

public class RemoteCaller{

    Service serviceCaller;

    public void remoteCall(String message) {

        class RemoteCallable implements Callable<Void> {
            String message;
            public RemoteCallable( String message)
            {
                this.message = message;
            }
            public Void call() throws Exception{
                serviceCaller.updateDetails( this.message);
                return null;
            }
        }


        RetriableHelper<Void> retriableHelper = new RetriableHelper<Void>(5, 500, new RemoteCallable( message));
        try {
            retriableHelper.call();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        } 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[enter link description here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry)    Spring has a retry annotation which servers the purpose

```
Step 1: Add following dependency to your POM

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


Step 2: Enabling Spring Retry

To enable Spring Retry in an application, we need to add the @EnableRetry annotation to our @Configuration class:

Ex:

@Configuration
@EnableRetry
public class AppConfig { ... }


Step 3: To add retry functionality to methods, @Retryable can be used:

Ex: 

@Service
public interface MyService {
    @Retryable(
      value = { SQLException.class }, 
      maxAttempts = 2,
      backoff = @Backoff(delay = 5000))
    void retryService(String sql) throws SQLException;
    ...
}


Step 4.The @Recover annotation is used to define a separate recovery method when a @Retryable method fails with a specified exception:

Ex: 

@Service
public interface MyService {
    ...
    @Recover
    void recover(SQLException e, String sql);
}


See Url for more details : http://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry
```

Answer (score 0):

where do you get the services from? use a factory to Proxy the service you get from the original factory. The proxy can then implement the retry transparently. See the java Proxy/ProxyGenerators in reflection.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring , then better go with Aspects. 
Otherwise, below sample solution can work:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.toRunFirst("Hello! This is normal invocation");
        runWithRetry(test, "toRunFirst", "Hello! This is First, called with retry");
        runWithRetry(test, "toRunSecond", "Hello! This is Second, called with retry");
    }


    public void toRunFirst(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    public void toRunSecond(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    public static Object runWithRetry(Object obj, String methodName, Object... args) throws Exception
    {
        Class<?>[] paramClass = new Class<?>[args.length];
        for(int i=0; i< args.length; i++) {
            paramClass[i] = args[i].getClass();
        }
        Method method = obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName, paramClass);

        int retryCount = 2;

        for(int i=0; i< retryCount; i++) {
            try {
                return  method.invoke(obj, args);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not find what I needed so there is mine.
The main feature is that it throws the type of Exception you need when maxRetries is reached so you can catch it in the call.

```java
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class TaskUtils {

    public static <E extends Throwable> void retry(int maxRetries, Task<E> task) throws E {
        retry(maxRetries, 0, null, task);
    }

    public static <E extends Throwable> void retry(int maxRetries, long waitTimeMs, Logger logger, Task<E> task) throws E {
        while (maxRetries > 0) {
            maxRetries--;
            try {
                task.run();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (maxRetries == 0) {
                    try {
                        throw e;
                    } catch (Exception ignored) { // can't happen but just in case we wrap it in
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }

                if (logger != null)
                    logger.warn("Attempt " + maxRetries + " failed", e);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(waitTimeMs);
                } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public interface Task<E extends Throwable> {
        void run() throws E;
    }
}
```

Usage :

```java
TaskUtils.retry(3, 500, LOGGER, () -> stmClickhouse.execute(
                        "ALTER TABLE `" + database + "`.`" + table.getName() + "` ON CLUSTER " + clusterName + allColumnsSql
                ));
```